# Converting Erros in progress using GPDL

Tags: c++, pdf, xps, spl

I came cross an error while converting a SPL file to PDF using the GXPS module, and tried my best but still can not find any clue to solve this,please anyone know this can help me with this.

The SPL file generated by the printer printing txt is in XPS format. The GXPS module has no problem converting the SPL file to PDF, but converting GPDL to SPL will generate a bunch of garbled files.

The GPDL module integrates the GXPS module. In theory, it should also be possible to convert SPL files into correct PDF files.

Look forward to your help.
Thanks.

Best Regards

Comment: I'm sure it makes sense to you, but I have no idea what any of these acronyms are or how C++ is involved. You need to edit your question to at least include a [mre] or an accurate description.